# Loading serialized classes

Tags: java, class, serialization, classloader

What is the easiest way to load a class that has been serialized using the standard Java Serialization API?

Is there any trivial relationship between the `.class` format and the serialized form of a `Class<?>` instance?

Answer (score 2):

> *Is there any trivial relationship between the .class format and the
>   serialized form of a Class instance?*

A Serializable class when compiled gets a identifier called the serialVersionUID ([SUID](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html#4100)). Each object that is serialized using this version of the class also gets stamped with this SUID.

> *What is the easiest way to load a class that has been serialized using
>   the standard Java Serialization API?*

Depends on what you are trying to achieve, *.class file as you would already know, consists of byte code in a series of bytes. Objects dont replicate the byte codes, so you cannot recover the byte series of its class from the serialized object. But you have the serialVersionUID as a final long variable in the serialized object. Using this information you can match the appropriate version of the *.class.

But thats more said than done, you would come across lots of interesting stuff while actually implementing this 'adaptive' loading.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking whether you can serialize a `Class<?>` object and then use that serialized file  as a `.class` file to load in a ClassLoader, then the answer is no.

Object serialization means you are saving the object state as a sequence of bytes. This is not the same as bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do to read the class file and converts into byte[] and write them into a file.

Then when deserlalizing, you would need load byte[] from files and define the class by default system classloader or self-defined classloader depends on your need.